# What is the use of the Display Name in the Email field of Contacts? (GAS)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-contacts-api

The EmailField class of ContactsApp has get/setDisplayName() methods. What can be a use for this display name?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The display name is used to mention the full representative name of the email ID (for Ex: abc xyz where abc xyz is the display name) . The functions give you the ability to fetch or change this information.

Comment: As far as I can tell none of my over 3000 Google contacts have this display name set. (Some of these contacts were automatically created from emails written, some where manually created on the web interface and some on android, while some where imported from elsewhere.) Where would it show up/make any difference if I add a display name to one of the email addresses? What application uses/displays this info?

Comment: Mail apps such as gmail and others will use this when displaying emails.